# JQuery Page Load Event to only run once

Tags: jquery, events, cart

My problem currently is I have:

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#update_cart_button").click();
    });
});
```

However, the button click itself also refreshes to the page to update cart values. Is there a way that I can make this button event fire only once and then when the page loads again from the button click it is not fired a second time? Currently this code causes the page to get stuck in an infinite loop of refreshing the page and pressing the `update_cart_button`.

Comment: You could store a flag in a cookie or localStorage on first load and then only trigger that click if the flag has not been set. This may result in problems when the user returns to the page at a later time, though. A better idea would be to avoid this issue completely. You could do that by only refreshing the required part of the page through AJAX.

Comment: I currently have no control over the button's functionality itself so I am just trying to find work around's for it. I appreciate the fast response however :)

Comment: I've fixed the issue, although it wasn't the most graceful of fixes. I managed to target any values that were £0 on the cart page and then fire the update_cart event if any are detected. This still means if any products are £0 as their actual price the page will still get stuck. It also means the page is essentially refreshed twice to get the actual cart values. But for now it will have to do